# R text mining - intersection between text fields

Tags: r, nlp, intersection, text-mining

I was wondering if there's a quick way to find directed intersection between 2 text strings e.g.

```
 t1 <- "I have achieved my goals over the past 20 years and look forward for my next chalanges"
 t2 <- " have achieved goals and look my chalanges some other words bla bla"
```

t1 isContainedIn t2 would return 7 because 7 words that apeared in t1 also apeared in t2 .
Also, t1 and t2 are 2 columns in a data frame, so I would need to apply that function on the entire data frame and attached the result column to my original data frame.
This is how my data frame 'data.selected' looks like:

```
        keywords                                         title
1  Samsung UN48H6350 48" Samsung UN48H6350 48" Full 1080p Smart HDTV 120Hz with Wi-Fi +$50 Visa Gift Card
2  Samsung UN48H6350 48"     Samsung UN48H6350 48" Full HD Smart LED TV -Bundle- (See Below for Contents)
3  Samsung UN48H6350 48"      Samsung UN48H6350 48" Class Full HD Smart LED TV -BUNDLE- See below Details
4  Samsung UN48H6350 48"     Samsung UN48H6350 48" Full HD Smart LED TV With BD-H5100 Blu-ray Disc Player
5  Samsung UN48H6350 48"                 Samsung UN48H6350 48" Smart 1080p Clear Motion Rate 240 LED HDTV
6  Samsung UN48H6350 48"            Samsung UN48H6350 - 48-Inch Full HD 1080p Smart HDTV 120Hz with Wi-Fi
7  Samsung UN48H6350 48"               Samsung 6350 Series UN48H6350 48" 1080p HD LED LCD Internet TV NEW
8  Samsung UN48H6350 48"  Samsung Un48h6350af 75" 1080p Led-lcd Tv - 16:9 - Hdtv 1080p - (un75h6350afxza)
9  Samsung UN48H6350 48"                         Samsung UN48H6350 - 48" HD 1080p Smart HDTV 120Hz Bundle
10 Samsung UN48H6350 48"   Samsung UN48H6350 - 48-Inch Full HD 1080p Smart HDTV 120Hz with Wi-Fi, (R#416)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess another similar way would by just to use a simple `match`

```
string <- strsplit(c(t1, t2), "\\s+") # similar to @Richard
length(na.omit(match(string[[2]], string[[1]])))
## [1] 7
```

Or maybe `lapply`

```
length(unlist(lapply(string[[2]], intersect, string[[1]])))
## [1] 7
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not exactly clear on what you mean by *direction matters*. The length of the intersection shouldn't change unless you change the data. This might be what you're looking for.

```
length(Reduce(intersect, strsplit(c(t1, t2), "\\s+")))
# [1] 7
```

If you switch `c(t1, t2)` to `c(t2, t1)` you can see the difference in the `Reduce` output. But as I said, the length will still be the same. It's only the order of the sets that differ.

Comment: you're right - intersection is not the right term. I meant to find how much t1 is contained in t2: how many terms that occur in t1, occur in t2 (not vis versa - direction matters)

Comment: Also - t1 and t2 are data frames - I'm not sure that this solution supports that as R returns character(0) currently when I run it on my data

Comment: @user3628777 - No, it doesn't.  That information would have been good to have from the beginning.  I'll make an edit, but we need to know:  What exactly are you comparing?  Keyword and title?  Please also show your desired result from your updated data frame in the question